# API call works in browser, but reports (incorrect?) redirect when called via PHP curl

Tags: php, json, api, curl

I have to build a script that convert the JSON we get from our partner company's API into an Xml file that our current software can read without much changing. Sounds simple enough, and the API is relatively simple as well - it's just that I can't seem to get the results when I call it, even though the exact same call works in the browser.

When I call an API function in the browser, I get a nice little JSON object in return, but when I try to call the exact same URL via curl in my PHP script, I get only a 302 - Moved response. The weird thing is, that redirect does not happen in the browser as far as I can see, and it also doesn't contain any content at all if I follow it (but it does belong to the other company).

I'm starting to suspect that it has something to do with the authorization. While I have checked and doublechecked the username and password about a million times, I have noticed that I get the same result if I deliberately use a wrong username/password combination. Another few things I've noticed:

- IE 9 accepts the login just fine
- Firefox often asks two or three times for the password before it accepts it and shows me the JSON result
- Opera as well as Chrome won't accept the login at all. It's definitely not typos - I'm copy&pasting the working password.

Now, I'm trying to make contact with a tech guy at that other company to talk this through with, but I'm beginning to think that this might be a more general problem that others might run into as well, so I decided to post this question here. Below is an excerpt from my script. I'm almost sure by now that I'm doing something stupid (or stupidly not doing something I should), and it would be nice if I could embarass myself somewhat anonymously on the internet instead of embarassing myself with real life tech guys.

Edit: changed the host in my script.

```
function curl_download($url, $username, $password)
{
    $http_headers = array(
                    'Host: www.myapidomain.com',
                    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2',
                    'Accept: */*',
                    'Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5',
                    'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7',
                    'Connection: keep-alive'
                  );

    $ch = curl_init();    

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $http_headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); Tried with and without that
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);

    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $output;
}

$username = '#username';
$password = '#password';
$url = $api_details.$myID; //something like example.com/api/?id=1234

//tried it with a context and file_get_contents once just for the kicks, but didn't work either
// $context = stream_context_create(array(
    // 'http' => array(
        // 'header'  => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password")
    // )
// ));
// $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$result = curl_download($url, $username, $password);
echo 'JSON: '.$result; //result is "302 Found - document has moved here". Following this gives absolutely no output in the browser or when following with curl.
```

Edit:
Okay, here is the request header:

```
(Request-Zeile)    GET /api/?id=100100 HTTP/1.1
Host    www.myapidomain.com
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language de-de,de;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
DNT 1
Cookie  MaD-Stats=42d1e7eb3c1dbcc59dd28e986ba9ceb3; 5991e5c00fce8acb72465bbca79260ecb=bc800030fa14aff2c5f726f1cfe3ffe7
Authorization   Basic fzBob66lajgybiRqYTglbGE5p2FtdTqmQmCmYZk=
Connection  keep-alive
Cache-Control   max-age=0
```

And here the response header:

```
(Status-Zeile) HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date    Thu, 13 Jun 2013 10:01:13 GMT
Server  Apache/2.2.23 (FreeBSD) PHP/5.2.17 mod_ssl/2.2.23 OpenSSL/1.0.1c
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.2.17
Set-Cookie  MaD-Stats=76d1a7eb2c1dbacfcdd2e5986b39ceb3; expires=Mon, 16-Dec-2013 10:01:14 GMT; path=/
Content-Length  602
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Type    text/html
```

Edit2:
So, in response to Eugene's question, I've set the correct host in my curl request. Now I get a 401 response, which makes a bit more sense. Is there something wrong with the way I set my login info?

Comment: Copy your browser's request headers and the server's response headers when you are making a successful API request and attach to this question. It might give a clue of what's going on.

Comment: Done. I should also mention that I've already tried saving the cookie, but it made no difference.

Comment: Are you using different hosts in curl and browser requests on purpose or is it a typo?

Comment: That was a mistake - I've edited my question. I now get a 401 Authorization Required response, so something is probably off with the way I set my username and password, but what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel stupid now, for two reasons:

1. The error that Eugene pointed out, namely that I used the wrong host in my header.
2. I then spent half the day figuring out why authorization failed, read documentation about curl functions and everything. Now I found the error: my password contained a `§` symbol, and the wrong password was sent only because of encoding. I put a `utf8_decode` around my password and now it works like a charm. Another mystery solved.